# Unable to print out answers when passing double values from functions (C language)

Tags: c, printf, double

The program is meant to receive double data type values. Then verify the data type using the custom function get_double and get the area/volume/circumference using corresponding functions and the provided values (double). There's a switch statement there but I don't think it is causing the issue.

I really have no idea where's the problem. I've tried to compile with two different compilers, and I still get it.

Since sharing just a snip of code I think is insufficient for understanding the problem. I think the solution must be rather simple, but since I'm a beginner in programming I can't see the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//OPTIONS
double volume (double radius, double height);   //V = volume
double area (double radius);                    //A = area
double circumf (double radius);                 //C = circumference
                                                //Q = quit
char get_option (void);
double get_double (void);

int main ()
{
    int salir = 0;
    char option;
    double radius, area_answer, circumference_answer, height, volume_answer;

    do {

        // fflush(stdin);
        //FFLUSH is important. It allows the buffer to be cleaned from the input entered when informing the program about the data needed (radius and height). Otherwise the DO WHILE loop is repeated additional and unnecerary times. IT CLEARS THE INPUT BUFFER!

        //OPTION to FFLUSH. It can be used this loop after every scanf in the code: while ((getchar()) != '\n'); THIS LOOP CLEARS THE BUFFER!


        printf("This program informs about he geometry of a circle (or a cylinder).\n");
        printf("Choose an option:\n"
                "\tA - Area\n\tC - Circumference\n\tV - Volume\n\tQ- Quit\n");
        option = get_option ();
        printf("\nThe selected option was: %c\n\n", option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 'a':
                printf("Enter the radius of the circle (double type) to know its area:\n");
                radius = get_double();
                area_answer = area(radius);
                printf ("The area of a circle with radius %f is: %f\n\n", radius, area_answer);
                while ((getchar()) != '\n');
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("Enter the radius of the circle (double type) to know its circumference:\n");
                radius = get_double();
                circumference_answer = circumf(radius);
                printf("The circumference of a circle with radius %f is: %f\n\n", radius, circumference_answer);
                while ((getchar()) != '\n');
                break;
            case 'v':
                printf("Enter the radius and height of the cylinder (double type) to know its volume:\n");
                radius = get_double();
                height = get_double();
                volume_answer = volume (radius, height);
                printf("The volume of a cylinder with radius %f and height %f is: %f\n\n", radius, height, volume_answer);
                while ((getchar()) != '\n');
                break;
            case 'q':
                salir = 1;
                printf("You have quitted the program.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Uknown option. Please, try again.\n\n");
                while ((getchar()) != '\n');
                break;
        }    
    } while (salir == 0);

    return 0;
}


//FUNCTIONS    
double volume (double radius, double height)
{
    double volume, PHI = 3.14;
        volume = PHI * radius * radius * height;
            return volume;
}

double area (double radius)
{
    double area = 0.0, PHI = 3.14;
        area = PHI * radius * radius;
        printf("PHI = %f\n", PHI);
        printf("radius = %f\n", radius);
        printf("area = %f\n\n", area);
            return area;
}

double circumf (double radius)
{
    double circumf, PHI = 3.14;
        circumf = 2.0 * PHI * radius;
            return circumf;
}

//GETTING CHAR OR DOUBLE
char get_option (void) // <------------------ this function is problematic
{
    char input_char;

    printf("> ");

    input_char = getchar();
    input_char = tolower (input_char);

    return input_char;
}

double get_double (void)
{
    double input_double;

    while ((scanf("%lf", &input_double) != 1))
    {
        while (getchar() != '\n')
        printf("> ");
    }

    printf("input_double = %f\n\n", input_double);
}
```

I think the problem could be somewhere in the function `get_double`, but I'm not sure. I've tried different approaches to solve the problem unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please put your code in your post and not somewhere it can be removed

Comment: 1) do not post links to external sites.  2) create a [MCVE] and edit your question and post the code.  What is the problem specifically?  You do not say.

Comment: Compile with all warnings turned on.  The issue should pop out.

Comment: Note that getchar() returns an int, not a char. Fix that first. Also note that PI is about 3.14,,,, but PHI is about 1.618..., a very different constant.

Comment: @Simon I'm new on the site. I haven't found in the documentation how to put my code in the post. If you provide me with a link to such information, I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'll follow the guidelines in future posts, I promise. I said what was the problem the best I could. Let me know where you need clarification. Right now I'm trying the possible solutions you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to write `return input_double;` at the end of the function `double get_double (void)` ... so this function returns garbage because you did not return any value.

Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Anas Hamed It worked! I'm a beginner in programming and on this site. Is it ok if I inform you that the solution you provided works or with me accepting your answer marking it is enough?